# Scala: alternative List syntax (with square brackets, if possible)

Tags: list, scala, syntax, syntactic-sugar

is there an alternative 'List' syntax in Scala?
Is it possible to define one aditional class/type/operator* called '[' and ']'?

I know 'square brackets' are used to indicate Type, but they are perfect to the repetitive task of declaring lists.

A ';' or '?' would be good also, as a last resource.

Thanks

obs.:
after much search the only alternative I found was to use 'cons':

```
val list = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

but it doesn't reduce any key typing at all.

- I am still learning those things in Scala

EDIT:
Just to clarify: Performance is not a priority in my case. And yes, shift is not welcome. :P
Motivation behind the scenes: I like Haskell style, but cannot use it directly with Java.

EDIT 2:
Final solution based on both Rex Kerr solutions

implementing object Types:

```
package a
object Types {
  type \[z] = List[z]
  implicit def make_lists[A](z: A) = new ListMaker(z)

  class ListMaker[A](a0: A) {
    private[this] val buffer = List.newBuilder[A]
    buffer += a0
    def \(z: A) = {
      buffer += z;
      this
    }
    def \\ = buffer.result
  }
}
```

using object Types:

```
package a
import a.Types._

object Whatever {
  def listInListOut (l: \[Int]) = {
    1\2\\
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using `List(1, 2, 3)`?

Comment: Just longer and shiftish than [1,2,3]. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly an alternative syntax, but it is by far the most portable solution:
In Intellij IDEA it is possible to create "Live Templates";
press Ctrl+Alt+s; search for "template"; go to "Live Templates" section;
just add one new item named "l" inside Scala entry, add a random description and the following code:

```
List($END$)
```

Press Enter, go to the editor, press L followed by Tab.
It is the end of your typing pains.
Do the same for Arrays.

Comment: You can even create macros and assign keyboard shortcuts to them. One of my favorites is `Ctrl+:` for adding a line to existing JSON code: `"": "",` The macro just types that out then goes back 6 characters.

Answer (score 12):

`[` and `]` are reserved symbols in Scala which are used for type annotations.  You can't use them for lists.  `;` is reserved for end of line.  You could use `?` in many cases, but it would be awkward.

I recommend that you learn to use the `::` notation (and get used to typing the `:` symbol fast twice in succession) because it really makes the list operations visually clear, plus it is a great syntactic reminder that lists are weird because you put things on the head of the list.

However, if you cannot tolerate this, your best option is probably to define a one-letter list symbol.  For example,

```
List(1,2,3,4)
```

is a list of the numbers from 1 to 4.  What if you could just type `L` instead of `List`?  It turns out that you can, since this is *not* a fancy constructor or static method, but a singleton companion object to the class `List`.  So you just

```
val L = List
L(1,2,3,4)
```

and you are just one character worse off than your suggestion of brackets.

Answer (score 4):

I can't help pointing out another way to go here for lists where all the elements are the same type, if you really hate the shift key and don't care if other people can understand your code:

```
class ListMaker[A](a0: A) {
  private[this] val buffer = List.newBuilder[A]
  buffer += a0
  def \(a: A) = { buffer += a; this }
  def \\ = buffer.result
}
implicit def make_lists[A](a: A) = new ListMaker(a)
```

Now you can list to your heart's content, without ever touching the shift key!

```
scala> val a = 1\2\3\4\5\\
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val b = 'a'\'b'\\
b: List[Char] = List(a, b)

scala> val c = false\true\false\false\false\false\true\\
c: List[Boolean] = List(false, true, false, false, false, false, true)
```

This uses exactly as many characters as brackets would.  (It doesn't nest well, however.)

Answer (score 3):

Define

```
def l[A](a:A*) = List(a:_*)
```

Then you can do

```
l(1,2,3)
```

which is only one character more than `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Ah--you beat me by 9 seconds! :)

Comment: My solution is clearly better because he will not have to use the shift key to type it. ;)

Comment: But Rexs implementation with L being a function valued val is much nicer.

Comment: @Jens Schauder - It's not a function (i.e. doesn't derive from `Function1`); it's just an alias to the `List` companion object.

Comment: @Kim Stebel - only if I use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to 'type it'. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0.r24777-b20110419020105 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class LM[A](x: A) {
     |   def \(y: A) = List(x,y)
     | }
defined class LM

scala> implicit def a2l[A](x: A): LM[A] = new LM(x)
a2l: [A](x: A)LM[A]

scala> class LX[A](xs: List[A]) {
     |   def \(y: A) = xs:::List(y)
     | }
defined class LX

scala> implicit def l2lx[A](xs: List[A]): LX[A] = new LX(xs)
l2lx: [A](xs: List[A])LX[A]

scala> 1\2
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> 1\2\3
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala>
```

Comment: Well, yes--but you're building up your list from the wrong end.  That's why I didn't do it this way.  Then again, maybe O(N^2) list creation is worth saving two more characters, as long as we're going that way :)

Comment: `scala> 1\2
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: ?{val \(x$1: ?>: Int(2) <: Any): ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method a2l in object $iw of type [A](x: A)LM[A]
 and method make_lists in object $iw of type [A](a: A)ListMaker[A]
 are possible conversion functions from Int to ?{val \(x$1: ?>: Int(2) <: Any): ?}
       1\2
       ^`